# 207 Multi-status response jQuery error with digest auth only works in incognito

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, hash, webdav

On an nginx+php-fpm server, I'm running a [carddav server](http://baikal-server.com) and [client](http://www.inf-it.com/open-source/clients/carddavmate/) based on SabreDAV and jQuery respectively. I can normally login, but with one exception: after some time, and possibly due to a failed login attempt, I can't login anymore with Chrome, unless I use incognito mode or a temporary vanilla preferences folder. In the console, I see the following error messages:

```
PROPFIND https://user:password@dav.server.com/d/card.php/principals/ 207 (Multi-Status) jquery.js:8434
send jquery.js:8434
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7986
[...]
Error: [netCheckAndCreateConfiguration: 'https://dav.server.com/d/card.php/principals/'] code: '401' webdav_protocol.js:135
```

Server-side logs don't seem to have a bit of difference between the failed logins and the successful. The client, having the credentials from the HTML form, sends their ajax request, gets a 401 response and retries with the proper authentication headers as you can see from the dev tools information:

```
Request URL:https://user:password@dav.server.com/d/card.php/principals/
Request Method:PROPFIND
Status Code:207 Multi-Status
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:UTF-8,*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:el,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
Authorization:Digest username="user", realm="BaikalDAV", nonce="516d8f8577751", uri="/d/card.php/principals/", response="53a29333f913bc5824d9ae94d4cdd573", opaque="df58bdff8cf60599c939187d0b5c54de", qop=auth, nc=00000001, cnonce="e22cc240959fa57b"
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:122
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:PHPSESSID=3f9bfd0909ba6f95888c525a3281f3c3
Depth:0
Host:dav.server.com
Origin:https://dav.server.com
Referer:https://dav.server.com/contacts/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22
X-client:CardDavMATE 0.10.1 (INF-IT CardDAV Web Client)
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

The server accepts the credentials and responds with `207 Multi-status` and these headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/xml; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 16 Apr 2013 17:51:01 GMT
DAV:1, 3, extended-mkcol, addressbook, access-control, calendarserver-principal-property-search
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/1.3.15
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Brief,Prefer
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.23
```

and this body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns" xmlns:card="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav">
  <d:response><d:href>/d/card.php/principals/</d:href>
      <d:propstat>
          <d:prop>
               <d:current-user-principal><d:href>/d/card.php/principals/user/</d:href></d:current-user-principal>
          </d:prop>
          <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
      </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

In incognito mode, the success callback in jQuery is called, and the client app proceeds and works as intended. In normal mode, the error callback is called even though the same exact information was exchanged with the server. This happens even if I clear all private data, passwords and any other option I could find in Chrome version 25.0.1364.160 Debian 7.0 (186726).

I have seen many questions about clearing authentication data from Chrome, and I have tried the usual suggestions (like sending a request to the server with a user@ in the URL), but I have no trouble sending requests manually. It's only the ajax call which fails for seemingly no reason at all.

In Firefox I have no problem, except that I sometimes get a browser authentication popup.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to using Firefox for this. The other alternative would be to patch Baikal to use http basic auth. At least according to the carddavmate developer.